# Establishing a proper conditional statement for strings in 2.7

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I'm scraping through various webpages and extracting a collection of numbers in a string named *Numbers*. For some of the webpages, the string *Numbers* comes out empty since none of what I'm looking for is within the webpage. The string *Numbers* can be of any length from empty to over 10000+.

My code reads an excel sheet where I specify the position of the number I am looking for within the string *Numbers*. This position is given by the variable *Position*. I would like to write a condition that would tell me if there is a number in the string *Numbers* at the position *Position* and if so, move on to other commands. My problem arises from the fact that the webpages I'm scraping are updated frequently. Therefore, the string *Numbers* changes length and what I was looking for at the position *Position* is no longer there. The string *Numbers* could be shorter it would result in an error using the following code:

```
if Numbers[Position]:
    move on with the code
else:
    print 'no number found'
```

I get

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

in the event that

1. The string *Numbers* is empty
2. There is no number at the position *Position* within the string *Numbers*

I would like to know what condition, adapted to the various scenario (empty string, shorter string), to have something like:

if there is a number at the position *Position* within *Numbers*, move on.  It would prevent my code from crashing.

Comment: Just a recommendation: Try to follow [Python naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the length:

```
if len(Number) > Position:
    # Number[Position] will work
```

or you could just catch the excepton:

```
try:
    result = Number[Position]
    # get here and it worked
except IndexError:
    # nope, no such position
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few checks here.

```
if numbers:
   # string is not empty
   try:
       print('Number at position {} is {}'.format(position, numbers[position]))
   except IndexError:
       # position doesn't exist
       print('{} does not exist in string'.format(position))
else:
   # string is empty
   print('String is empty')
```

If you don't want to be that specific, since slices are always less than the length of the string, you can just do:

```
if len(numbers) > position:
    print('Number at position {} is {}'.format(position, numbers[position]))
else:
    print('{} does not exist'.format(position))
```